# @Table annotation and the need set catalog or schemas for development or deployment

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

Here's my problem.

When I'm developing I usually have a persistence class configured to H2 with @Profile("development") mapped to a local database on my computer. At the same time, I have another persistence class mapping the same entities, which is basically a copy of the first one, only configured to MySQL. These persistence classes are picked up by Spring depending on the @Profile annotation, the second one is annotated with @Profile("default")

My problem is that when I deploy the @Profile("default") is picked up and  MySQL needs the @Table annotation to be like this:

```
@Table(name = "tableName", catalog = "databaseName")
```

While on development, H2 understands only this:

```
@Table(name = "tableName", schema = "databaseName")
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? Some conditional way to switch the @Table annotation from schema to catalog on deployment?

Comment: Do you really have to set catalog and schema? I would try to set them on connection url or datasource.

Comment: Yes, because some entities are in different schemas on the same server. Setting it on the URL would break it or I'd need to create 1 more persistence for every database on the same server.

Comment: Did you sollved it?

Comment: I had to look at the code to remember, but apparently, I gave up and used a MySQL instance for tests instead of H2.

Comment: having the same issue... someone maybe solved it?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behavior in Spring, conditional bean configuration and conditional annotations can be used.

```
 @Configuration
    public class EntityConfiguration {
    
        @Profile("development")
        static class H2Configuration {
            @Bean
            public JpaRepository<H2Entity, Long> h2Repository() {
                return new JpaRepository<H2Entity, Long>();
            }
        }
    
        @Profile("default")
        static class MySQLConfiguration {
            @Bean
            public JpaRepository<MySQLEntity, Long> mysqlRepository() {
                return new JpaRepository<MySQLEntity, Long>();
            }
        }
    }
```

In this configuration, the active Spring profile will be used for identifying the correct entity class and database environments.I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue like you did. While searching for possible solutions, i found the following article:
https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-set-the-schema-name-dynamically-in-spring-jpa-b0f1c2205ad2

You can dynamically change the schema / catalog by overriding the `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`. However we don't need to change it dynamically but we do need to remove the catalog qualifier while being in a test / development environment and only use the schema qualifier.

The entity now looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_for_entity", schema = "schemaName", catalog = "schemaName")
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntityName {
...
}
```

Note that we annotate both the schema and the catalog.
To remove the catalog in a testing environment, you need to override the `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` . In our case we used (the deprecated) SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy. The overriden Configuration will look something like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        if (name != null) {
            return super.toPhysicalCatalogName(null, jdbcEnvironment);
        }
        return super.toPhysicalCatalogName(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }
}
```

This configuration will only be created in a testing / development environment and will override the catalog name. The does nothing more than checking oif there is a catalog name set and removes it.
You then need to set the `CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy` in the application.yml file. For my case it was enough to configure it in the test package.
Configuration will look like this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: ch.soobr.domain.config.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

All in all to be as close as possible to production, its still recommended to use testcontainers.