# @Table annotation and the need set catalog or schemas for test and production code

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

Basically i have the same question as:
[@Table annotation and the need set catalog or schemas for development or deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003817/table-annotation-and-the-need-set-catalog-or-schemas-for-development-or-deploym)

However I tried a few more approaches on how to solve this which I wanted to add here. The original question is more than 6 years old without an answer...

One approach i tried which felt actually ok:
Setting the code catalog / schema manually on startup via reflection. There it's clear if i am in the test environment and therefore need to set the catalog or if i'm in a non-test environment and i need to set the schema.
I tried different approaches for this. One would be:

```
@Component
public class TableAnnotationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Profile("test")
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    if (event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("test")) {
        adjustTableAnnotations();
    }
}

private void adjustTableAnnotations() {
    Table tableAnnotation = EntityClass.class.getAnnotation(Table.class);
    if (tableAnnotation != null) {
        String schemaOrCatalog = "your_h2_schema"; // Set the schema for H2 or catalog for MySQL
        try {
            Field schemaField = Table.class.getDeclaredField("schema");
            schemaField.setAccessible(true);
            Field catalogField = Table.class.getDeclaredField("catalog");
            catalogField.setAccessible(true);

            // Set the schema or catalog based on the active profile
            if (activeProfile.equals("test")) {
                schemaField.set(tableAnnotation, schemaOrCatalog);
                catalogField.set(tableAnnotation, ""); // Empty string for catalog
            } else {
                schemaField.set(tableAnnotation, "");
                catalogField.set(tableAnnotation, schemaOrCatalog);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error updating @Table annotation", e);
        }
    }
}
```

However this is still to late somehow. I never enter the code before the error occurs, that the table can't be found on startup.
So, maybe someone has a solution / idea on how to do this smoothly.

Comment: i answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321415/11978873

Answer (score 0):

Don't use H2 for testing when you run MySql in production.
Use Testcontainers instead.

If you really want to keep you approach you could alter the byte code using a [Java Agent](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation).